# Calculating axis length in proportion to fixed related length

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

**Basics**

I am working on a small tool that is supposed help with some geometric calculations for print-related products.

**Overview**

I have two inputs (`w` and `h`) where the user is supposed to enter a width and a height for a box. This box is supposed to be a representation of the users measurements as a small CSS-based box.

The problem is that I cannot just take the measurements and apply them as pixels, or even `pixels * 10`, or anything, as width/height for the display box, because my space is limited.

The box can have a maximum measurement of `69 x 69`.

What I want to achieve is that to apply the longer entered measurement to its according axis, then calculate the other axis in proportion to this.

**My approach**

I am not a maths person *at all*. But I did my best and I put together a function that will accomplish the above:

```
updateRectBox: function(w, h){

    // define maximum width and height for box
    var max_x=69;
    var max_y=69;
    var factor,x,y;

    factor=w/h;

    if(w==h){

        // if we have a 1:1 ratio, we want the box to fill `69px` on both axis
        x=max_x;
        y=max_y;

    } else {

        if(w>h){

            // if width is larger than height, we calculate the box height using the factor
            x=max_x;
            y=(factor>1 ? max_y/factor : max_y*factor);

        } else {

            // if height is larger than width, we calculate the box width using the factor
            x=(factor>1 ? max_x/factor : max_x*factor);
            y=max_y;

        }

    }

    // using this to set the box element's properties
    jQuery('#rect').css({
        'width': (x)+'px',
        'height': (y)+'px'
    });

}
```

This function works well, but:

**Question**

I know this can be done more beautifully, with less code. But due to my lack of math skills, I just cannot think of anything more compact than what I wrote.

[I've created a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utm7r/) to make it easier for you to test your optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function accomplishes exactly what it needs to. There are ways which are arguably more elegant to write, however.

The basic idea is that you have a box with dimensions (`w` × `h`) and you want a box which is a scaled version of this one to fit in a (69 × 69) box.

To fit in a (69 × 69) box, your (`w` × `h`) box must be less than 69 wide, and less than 69 tall. Suppose you scale by the quantity `s`. Then your new box has dimension (`s * w` × `s * h`). Using the above constraint, we know that:

`s * w <= 69` and that `s * h <= 69`. Rewrite these, solving for `s`, and you get:

`s <= 69 / w` and `s <= 69 / h`. Both must hold true, so you can rewrite this as:

`s <= min( 69 / w, 69 / h)`. In addition, you want `s` to be as large as possible (so the box completely fills the region) so `s = min( 69 / w, 69 / h)`.

Your code accomplishes the same, but through if-statements. You can rewrite it considerably terser by doing:

```
updateRectBox: function(width, height) {

    // define maximum width and height for box
    var max_width = 69;
    var max_height = 69;
    var scale = Math.min( max_width / width, max_height / height );

    var x = scale * width;
    var y = scale * height;

    // using this to set the box element's properties
    jQuery('#rect').css({
        'width': x+'px',
        'height': y+'px'
    });
}
```

Changing the variable names helps make it slightly more readable (`w` and `h` presumably do mean width and height, but making this explicit is helpful).

All this said, it's unlikely that there will be noticeable performance differences between this and your original. The code is extremely fast, since it does very little. That said, I made a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/ifs-vs-minimum) which shows that using `Math.min` is about 1.7 times faster on my browser.

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for. Well explained, too. Thank You!